# Stacked bar chart: how to define fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Once again, I need your help and I'm looking forward to listen & learn.

I would like to depict the interrelation between several types of birds (t1 - t7). It is observed how frequently they interact with their own type or other types of birds (o1 - o7)

The data (bird.data) looks as follows:

| type | o1 | o2 | o3 | o4 | o5 | o6 | o7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | 77.6 | 3.5 | 1.5 | 9.1 | 3.3 | 1.4 | 3.6 |
| t2 | 10 | 64.4 | 9 | 3.2 | 2.1 | 7.4 | 3.9 |
| t3 | 8.6 | 12.1 | 63.2 | 2.4 | 0.6 | 8.8 | 4.3 |
| t4 | 28.7 | 5.1 | 2.0 | 51.4 | 5.8 | 0.3 | 6.6 |
| t5 | 4.1 | 12.2 | 9.5 | 1.0 | 0.4 | 64.5 | 8.3 |
| t6 | 10.9 | 3.6 | 0.3 | 6.5 | 66.8 | 2.0 | 9.9 |
| t7 | 15.9 | 8.2 | 4.5 | 5.6 | 9.4 | 5.4 | 51.0 |

```
bird.data <- structure(list(type = c("t1”, “t2", “t3”, “t4”, “t5”, “t6”, “t7”), o1 = c(77.6, 10, 8.6, 28.7, 4.1, 10.9, 15.9), o2 = c(3.5, 64.4, 12.1, 5.1, 12.2, 3.6, 8.2), o3 = c(1.5, 9, 63.2, 2, 9.5, 0.3, 4.5), o4 = c(9.1, 3.2, 2.4, 51.4, 1, 6.5, 5.6), o5 = c(3.3, 2.1, 0.6, 5.8, 0.4, 66.8, 9.4), o6 = c(1.4, 7.4, 8.8, 0.3, 64.5, 2, 5.4), o7 = c(3.6, 3.9, 4.3, 6.6, 8.3, 9.9, 51)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

To show this graphically, I want to plot a flipped, stacked bar chart - similar to this one:
[image]
(Taken from this post: [Add percentage labels to stacked bar chart ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936123/add-percentage-labels-to-stacked-bar-chart-ggplot2))

Instead of County, I want to depict the different types of birds on the x-axis (type), instead of Plan Types I want to fill the bar with the percentage of interactions between the different types of birds (o1-o7).

My questions now are:

- How do I organize/group columns o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7 to be used as fill?
- What is my y?

```
ggplot() +
geom_bar(aes(y = ?, x = type, fill = ?),
         data = bird.data,
         stat="identity") +
         coord_flip()
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any advice! :-)

**EDIT:**
I have implemented the great suggestions by stefan, and now encountered another problem:

When adding labels to the stacked bar chart, vjust=0.5 does not place them in the middle of the respective bar:

````
```
ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = value, y = type, fill = name), 
           data = bird_data_long,
           position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev) +
  geom_label(data = subset(bird_data_long, value > 10), 
            aes(x = value, y = type, label = paste0(round(value, digits = 0),"%")), 
            size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```
````

The plot looks like this:
[image: Stacked Bar with Labels]

My question therefore is: how can I adjust the position of the labels so that they are placed exactly in the middle of the bar they are representing? Any idea why they are skewed? Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result by converting your data to long format using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer`. Afterwards it's pretty straightforward what should be mapped on `fill` and `y`.

Note: Instead of `geom_bar(.. stat="identity")` I use `geom_col(...)`. Also instead of `coord_flip` I switched the role of `x` and `y`.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

bird_data_long <- bird.data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-type, names_to = "name", values_to = "value")

head(bird_data_long)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   type  name  value
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 t1    o1     77.6
#> 2 t1    o2      3.5
#> 3 t1    o3      1.5
#> 4 t1    o4      9.1
#> 5 t1    o5      3.3
#> 6 t1    o6      1.4

ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = value, y = type, fill = name), data = bird_data_long)
```

[image]

**EDIT** The main issue is that you subsetted the data in `geom_text`. Hence you are stacking a different set of values compared to the bars so that the positions of the labels no longer correspond to the positions of the bars. To get rid of labels for smaller bars use an `ifelse` instead. This way your labels are placed at the correct positions.

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = value, y = type, fill = name), 
           data = bird_data_long,
           position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev) +
  geom_label(data = bird_data_long, 
             aes(x = value, y = type, group = name, label = ifelse(value > 10, paste0(round(value, digits = 0),"%"), NA)), 
             size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5,reverse = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was super helpful! How would you proceed to show labels on the stacked bars?

If I use geom_text like this:

```geom_text(data = bird_data_long, x = value, y = type, label = value, size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))```

I receive the error: Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomText,  : 
  object 'value' not found.

Any idea why value is not recognized?

Comment: You have to wrap the mapping in `aes()`: `geom_text(data = bird_data_long, aes(x = value, y = type, label = value), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))`

Comment: Any idea about my edit above?

Comment: See my edit: Never subset your data when stacking. (;