# Creating a Stacked Percentage Bar Chart in R with ggplot with labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that has the variables "SEXO" (M or F) and "Class" (0 or 1). I want to create a bar plot using ggplot2 that shows, for each sex, the distribution of Class as a percentage. I was able to get the plot, but I can't seem to get the labels working on the bars itself. I don't want to change the labels on the axis, I just want to get the % shown on the plot for each SEXO.

This is the code I have been using:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = SEXO, fill = Class)) + geom_bar(position = 'fill')
```

I also attach an image of the plot produced by the code:
[image]

This would be the ideal outcome:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw stacked bars in ggplot2 that show percentages based on group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231124/how-to-draw-stacked-bars-in-ggplot2-that-show-percentages-based-on-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example using the `mtcars` dataset where you can calculate the percentage per group and use these to place in your bars using `label` with `geom_text` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, vs) %>%
  summarise(cnt = n()) %>%
  mutate(perc = round(cnt/sum(cnt), 2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(vs), fill = factor(am), y = perc)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'fill') +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(perc*100,"%"), y = perc), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3) +
  labs(fill = 'Class', x = 'vs') +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'am'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>